# Arquivo Css com imagem dentro

Tags: java, css, imagem, spring

Pessoa estou tentando setar dentro do css uma imagem, para isso estou usando:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #C0C4C5 url(images/page-body-bg.png) repeat;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #2E2E2E;
}
```

Consigo acessar tranquilamente através do clink:

```
http://localhost:8080/Spring4MVCHelloWorldDemo/images/page-body-bg.png
```

o Problema: não está carregando a imagem, já tentei:

```
background: #C0C4C5 url(images/page-body-bg.png) repeat;
background: #C0C4C5 url(/images/page-body-bg.png) repeat;
background: #C0C4C5 url(./images/page-body-bg.png) repeat;
background: #C0C4C5 url(../images/page-body-bg.png) repeat;
```

a minha pasta está assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e o mapeamento no spring.servlet.xml está assim:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/WEB-INF/images/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/WEB-INF/css/" />
```

Comment: Desse jeito aqui `url(../images/page-body-bg.png) repeat;` deveria funcionar. Você limpou o cache do navegador entre as tentativas? Talvez o navegador utilizou a primeira "versão" do arquivo css em todas as suas tentativas, ou seja, ignorou todas as edições.

Comment: eu estou usando o proprio navegador que é aberto no eclipse, tb tem cache nesse navegador?

Comment: O eclipse não possui um navegador próprio, ela apenas utiliza o navegador padrão no seu OS, basta você limpar o cache dele. Você também pode ir direto no próprio navegador, acessar a página e forçar o carregamento, acredito que na maioria dos navegadores o atalho é `Ctrl + F5`. Outra opção é utilizar o navegador com o cache desabilitado nas Ferramentas de Desenvolvedor.

Comment: Aparentemente seu css deveria funcionar, mas tente colocar a imagem no mesmo path do css, e depois va mudando a imagem de path e ajustando seu css. deve ser algum outro detalhe outro ao codigo.